# Is there a good reason for a ListView header taking up a position?

Tags: android, listview, header, android-cursor

I've just added a header to my ListView and I have to change a bunch of code because the header essentially becomes position 0 (Meaning the Cursor indices of my CursorAdapter do not line up with the indicies of the list.  They are off by 1 now).  Why?  This seems a bit silly to me.

The only reason I can come up with is that a developer may want to access the header.  Fine.  Provide something like getListView().getHeader().

Comment: Just wait until you have to put in your own section headers. That's a nightmare.

Comment: So long as you're referring to the Adapter associated with the list, you shouldn't have any off-by-one problems. Adding headers/footers wraps your Adapter and does these adjustments for you.

Comment: I can put in my own section headers just fine.  With an ArrayAdapter, my section headers are actual list items.  With a CursorAdapter, each item has a header as part of its View, but it is only shown for the top item of each section.  The problem with both of these approaches is the header disappears; so you could end up with a list full of items and not know what header they're under because the header has scrolled off the top of the screen.  I was experimenting with ListView headers to get around this, but apparently they scroll off as well.

Answer (score 22):

For some reason the `position` (from the `onItemClick`) is tied up with the number of items in the `ListView` (**not the adapter**), including headers and footers. When you set an `OnItemClickListener` you should retrieve the clicked item by calling `listView.getItemAtPosition(position)` instead of `adapter.getItem(position)`.

In fact, you should always use the `getItemAtPosition`, because that way not matter if your `ListView` has headers and footers, and if you add new headers you won't need to change your code.

And if you don't want your header to be selectable, you should add it in this way: `listView.addHeaderView(headerView, null, false)`.

Answer (score 1):

I believe a `ListView` is nothing more than a list of `View` elements. If you add a header (or a footer for that matter, it shouldn't make any difference) to your `ListView`, that element is basically no different from any of the other elements that gets added automatically through the `ListAdapter`. The only minor difference being that the header (and footer) element will be fixed and stay unaffected by what the `ListAdapter` does with the list - they are still nothing but ordinary elements though.