# IndexOutOfBoundsException in ArrayAdapter

Tags: android

I got a trivial code involving a `ListView` and a `ArrayAdapter` which throws a IndexOutOfBoundsException on some devices. The problem is: I do not know how this Exception occurs, I only get the stacktraces from the Developer Console of Android.

The reduced code example is shown below. How can the `getItem` operation of the `ArrayAdapter` fail for the `position` element? The `ArrayAdapter` is never changed, there is no other method in the `Activity`.

**I know what a `IndexOutOfBoundsException` is, I know that I can prevent it by checking the length first. But I'm curious: How can this Exception happen here? How can someone click on a event which does not exist in the datastructure?**

Reduced code:

```
public class EventListActivity extends Activity {
    public void onStart() {
        final ListView listview = new ListView(this);
        final Event[] events = [Retrieve a Array from somewhere]
        final ArrayAdapter<Event> a = new ArrayAdapter<Event>(this, R.layout.eventlistitem, events);
        listview.setAdapter(a);
        listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Event event = a.getItem(position);
                                ^^^^^^^ throws Exception
            }
        });
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException
at java.util.Arrays$ArrayList.get(Arrays.java:75)
at android.widget.ArrayAdapter.getItem(ArrayAdapter.java:298)
at xxx.EventListActivity$3.onItemClick(EventListActivity.java:130)
```

Comment: It means ... that element doesn't exist in the array. Check the length first.

Comment: Okay, my question was not clear, I changed it. I already fixed the error, its just a question why it is happening here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I debugged it, in case someone has the same error, here is the solution:

If you use `ListView.addHeader`, the `position` argument of the `onItemClick` is shifted by 1. Seems quite weird because the position then has nothing to do with the position in the array-adapter. [This SO Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4027997/is-there-a-good-reason-for-a-listview-header-taking-up-a-position) contains the same conclusion, you have to pay attention what you add as headers.

My question above was in fact not very helpfull because the whole `addHeader` part was missing, it was impossible to answer the question by others, sorry. Nevertheless, this answer might be helpfull for others.

Comment: mark your answer correct so it'll be in the answered side not the unanswered side.

Comment: Why is it "on some" devices then?

Comment: BillGary: currently can not mark my answer as accepted, two days limit for this!
Asahi: You are right, its not device dependant, it was my fault of not searching at the right place.

Comment: you should probably correct your question and add missing details - it will make perfectly valid both the question and the answer

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well. but I'm adding two footers that I toggle View.Visible and View.GONE when need. Can this also be the answer to my exception. (I can never reproduce the exception to test, just crash reports)